# jQuery - Check if image is visible

Tags: jquery

I'm using sequencer.js to create an image sequence animation via mobile. I am trying to catch the src of the img.sequencer tag, and display the overlay if it is visible. Currently, my jQuery is this:

```
<div id="images">
    <img class="sequencer" src="./images/0.jpg">
</div>
<div id="over_1" class="overlay">
    <img src="#" />
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if ($('img.sequencer[src="./images/22.jpg"]').is(':visible')){
        $('#over_1').css({'display':'block'});
    }
});
```

However, this does nothing. Utilizing '!' on the src attribute displays the div, but not on visible (i.e. display on page load). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `#` means there is no image so you could do something like this

```
var image = $('#over_1').children().attr('src');
if (image != '#' && image != '') {
    $('#over_1').css({'display':'block'});
}
```

If you want to keep using the `visible` then you could do it this way

```
$("#over_1").find('img').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':visible')){
     alert("This image is visible");
    }
});
```

Comment: My question seemed misleading - Edited. The '#' will actually be the overlay (whether a div or just an image), but needs to trigger when the img.sequencer src meets requirements. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What about my second example using `visible`?

Comment: No dice. It displays the image on load, but not on visible. I'm willing to abandon visible, I really just need a way to check if the div HAS the specific file name.